# Botón que al clickearlo cambia un texto en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy empezando a aprender *Javascript* desde cero y he hecho este ejercicio básico de un botón que cambia un texto por otro al clickearlo. Al ejecutarlo en en navegador, no funciona. Quiero aprender en qué estoy fallando.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>prueba</title>
        <script>
            var color = document.getElementById("color");
            var color2 = "amarillo";
        function cambiarColor() {
            color.innerHTML = color2;
        } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="color"><h1>rojo</h1></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="cambiar" onclick="cambiarColor()">¡Cambiar!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debe cargarse todos los elementos de html, por eso sale `null`, por lo tanto tu script deberia estar situado debajo.

y si lo usas en un archivo externo el .js deberas agregar en un inicio esta linea de codigo: 
            `window.onload=function(){`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>prueba</title>
            
        </head>
        <body>
        
            <p id="color"><h1>rojo</h1></p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button id="cambiar" onclick="cambiarColor()">¡Cambiar!</button>
            <script>
                var color = document.getElementById("color");
                var color2 = "amarillo";
            function cambiarColor() {
                color.innerHTML = color2;
            } 

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Por qué pasa que se añade "amarillo" en vez de reemplazarse rojo por amarillo?

Comment: @amenadiel, eso pasa porque un `p` no puede contener un `h1` y el navegador al prosesar el `HTML` crea al `p` y al `h1` como elementos hermanos.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Excelente respuesta. Aunque esa regla tenía sentido más bien en la época de html3

Comment: Ojo: no necesariamente tiene que hacerse en el evento `load`. Ten en cuenta que si la web tiene recursos multimedia pesaditos, tu código se ejecutará con un gran delay. Para evitar eso puedes usar `DOMContentLoaded` en su lugar.

Answer (score 8):

Hay que hacer varios cambios.

- Quitar la siguiente línea, ya que *Javascript* ya declara la variable `color` automáticamente a partir del `id`.

```
var color = document.getElementById("color");
```

- Pasar la variable `color2` dentro de la función `cambiaColor`, pero tampoco es necesario tener la variable, ya que se puede asignar directamente.
- Cambiar lugar del `id`, quitándolo en `p` y agregándolo en `h1`.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
  function cambiarColor() {
   color.innerHTML=color.innerHTML=="rojo"?"amarillo":"rojo";
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><h1 id="color">rojo</h1></p>
  <button id="cambiar" onclick="cambiarColor()">¡Cambiar!</button>
 </body>
</html>
```